# Incorrect syntax near ',' AseBulkCopy

Tags: c#, sql-server, sap-ase

I have a code to implement a bulk copy from MSSQL SERVER to SYBASE (12.5) using ASE client, but at the WriteToServer() function i always get the error " Incorrect syntax near ','". NOTE: i have even changed the DestinationTableName to a table that does not exist, but i still get the same error.
my Code below

```
using (AseConnection theCons = new AseConnection(connstring))
{          
    try
    {
        if (theCons.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            theCons.Open();
        }

        AseBulkCopy objbulk = new AseBulkCopy(theCons);

        objbulk.DestinationTableName = "dbo.testBulk";

        try
        {
            objbulk.WriteToServer(dt); //dt is my source DataTable from MSSQL SERVER
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {

        }
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {

    }
    finally
    {
        if (theCons != null)
        {
            if (theCons.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
                theCons.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: See following webpage : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/09esk03d(v=vs.110).aspx.  You are missing a bulkCopy.DestinationTableName

Comment: @jdweng i have a bulkcopy DestinationTableName  ="testBulk"

Comment: Does the connection string have a default database?  The msdn example has 'dbo' which is a user database.  The error message is probably due to a parameter missing which I think is due to the database name not being declared (not sure).  The database can be declared either in the connection string as the default datbase or a part of the Tablename (using the period to separate database name from table).

Comment: Yes my connection string has a default database, and i just added dbo with a period to my destination table name but still the same.

Comment: Side note: Your code swallows exceptions. If anything gone wrong, how can you know it?

Comment: @zohar peled i have a file it writes to, i didnt include it.

Comment: Make sure your connection string doesn't contain any errors.

Comment: @jdweng thanks for your reply, it doesnt contain any errors because if it did i dont think aseconnection.open() would work.

Comment: @chikor.net, do the source and destination column names conform to normal identifier naming rules (e.g. no embedded spaces)?

Comment: The connection string may be opening up the database but doesn't use the default database.  So the connection string may still contain an error with the default database.  The when you perform the bulkcopy the default database name is invalid giving the error.

Comment: @Dan Guzman infact i have tried making it just a column source and destination just 1 column it is still same, i have even trie replaing the destination tablename with a table that doesnt exist in my sybase yet it is still the same

Comment: @chikor.net, so the DataTable column in your test conforms to normal identifier naming rules?

Comment: @Dan Guzman yes they do. Initially i had an error of 'could not find sp_oledb_columns' which i got the procedure from http://www.sqlbrowser.com/wikiHTML/sqlbhtml/sybsystemprocs/sp_oledb_columns.html and ever since then i now get 'incorrect syntax near ',''

Comment: @Dan Guzman i just noticed if i drop the sp_oledb_columns procedure i now get the error 'stored procedure sp_oledb_columns not found', it means my problem is coming from sp_oledb_columns. But how then do i go about solving it?

Comment: Please who has a solution to my problem?

Answer (score 0):

This error generated, when provider cannot find target table and use empty table name to query metadata for bulk copy (yep, checking operation results is not for real developers...).

In your case problem lies in "dbo.testBulk" line. E.g. your table named `TestBulk` (Title-case) or not in dbo schema.

Hint how to debug it. ASE client use following code to get table schema:

```cs
cn.GetSchema("columns", new object[] {tableName, ownerName, databaseName });
```

so you need to put your `dbo` and `testBulk` components here and see if it will return columns metadata.